# How can I open a new window inside a script, ssh to a different user and run commands?

Tags: xterm

0
￼
￼
I want to open a new terminal with minicom or ssh connection and run commands with a different user in that new window, using a shell script. I tried inside the shell script to write the following commands:

```
#! /usr/bin/tcsh -f

set Flag1 = 1
while ($Flag1)
   if ($Flag1)then 
          `xterm -e /home/Script/First.sh`
          set Flag1 = 0
   endif 
end
```

```
cat /home/Script/First.sh
```

```
#! /usr/bin/tcsh -f

sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0 
ifconfig eth0 10.120.140.3
ping -w20 10.120.140.1
```

The first command (minicom) worked, but it didn't continue to the other ones.

Comment: You are tagging this as 'bash', but you don't have statements which would adhere to bash syntax in your first script.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly but if you want execute one command after another use cmd1 && cmd2
So, if you want exec command after ssh connection:

```
minicom... ssh tal@ip 'ifconfig && ping'
```

and add shebang as first line of your script:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Comment: It didn't work..
It is trying to run the commands before it is connected to the serial port.
and when i'm trying to run with : sudo minicom -S /home/Script.sh -D /dev/ttyUSB0
it is shows:
script "/home/Scripts.sh" line 3: unknown variable "="

Comment: You are using tcsh (not sh) so no space with set:
set Flag1=1    #or use setenv:
setenv Flag1 1